# Is it possible to allow only a certain secure USB boot media to boot an UEFI system?

Tags: boot, debian, uefi, secure-boot, tpm

I want to restrict all USB boot media from my system, except for a certain USB boot drive that I declare secure via a certain key.

Is this possible using UEFI/Secure Boot/TPM? Maybe via TPM? TPM gets a private key and checks if public key on USB boot drive is valid?

It's a Debian Linux system.

Comment: This question might do better at serverfault or informationsecurity or maybe another stackexchange site I am unfamiliar with. Hopefully someone can answer you here as this is a good & hard question in my eyes

Comment: There are likely a couple options.  You can use USB port covers to avoid the use of other ports being used. You can use passwords to lock the UEFI configuration and boot order.  You can use BitLocker to lock down the system, when any configuration chance is required, due to the immediate requirement for the BitLocker recovery key. TPM only stores keys.  You can connect the flash media device directly to the USB header by using an appropriate cable and then lock the case so it cannot be accessed.

Comment: You might be able to allow Windows' *usage* by device GUID (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/configuration/administrative-templates-restrict-usb), and you can password-restrict BIOS/UEFI and set it to prevent *any* USB boot (https://www.groovypost.com/howto/disable-boot-usb-cd-bios-setup/), but I do not know an answer to your question, i.e., restrict boot to a single external device, which seems a reasonable request.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, should've stated, that it's a Linux system.

Comment: The common way is to encrypt the whole system, then it doesn't matter what USB devices some one uses to boot -your Linux data will not be accessible.